# Save changes to different datatables in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm writing a Shiny app that allows users to view and change multiple data frames. Ultimately, I'd like the changes to overwrite values in the original data frames so that they can be used in a calculation. Below is what I have so far. I've figured out how to allow the user to switch between dataframes, change values for the dfs, and "reset" the changes to the original values for df1 and df2. But I'd like to add an observeEvent that overwrites df1 and df2 with user changes.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
df1 <- data.frame(a = c('a','b','c','d','e'), 
                  b = round(rnorm(5, 0,1),2))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c('a','b','c','d','e'), 
                  b = round(rnorm(5, 1,1.5),2))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "df",
                  label = "Choose a table:",
                  choices = c("df1", 
                              "df2")),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
      actionButton("save", "Save Changes"),
      DTOutput("df")

      )
    )
  )
server <- function(input, output) {
  dfInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$df,
           "df1" = df1,
           "df2" = df2)
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    output$df <- renderDT(dfInput(), editable = TRUE,
                          options = list(lengthChange = FALSE))
  })

  output$df <- renderDT(dfInput(), editable = TRUE,
                        options = list(lengthChange = FALSE))
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `observeEvent` and record any edits made in real-time, instead of waiting for user to hit save button. If that approach works for you, then this might be helpful.

Note that you only need one `output` instead of two, and that `reset` will automatically revert to original data. To do this, you can use `reactiveValues` to store your data. In this case, I made a `list` of two data frames for `df1` and `df2`.

Also, to allow for testing with edits in this example, I added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your two data.frames when created (so edits not limited to factor levels).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

df1 <- data.frame(a = c('a','b','c','d','e'), 
                  b = round(rnorm(5, 0,1),2),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(a = c('a','b','c','d','e'), 
                  b = round(rnorm(5, 1,1.5),2),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "df",
                  label = "Choose a table:",
                  choices = c("df1", 
                              "df2")),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
      #actionButton("save", "Save Changes"),
      DTOutput("df")          
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(tables = list("df1" = df1, "df2" = df2))

  dfInput <- reactive({
    rv$tables[[input$df]]
  })

  observeEvent(input[["df_cell_edit"]], {
    cell <- input[["df_cell_edit"]]
    rv$tables[[input$df]][cell$row, cell$col] <- cell$value
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    rv$tables <- list("df1" = df1, "df2" = df2)
  })

  output$df <- renderDT(dfInput(), editable = TRUE,
                        options = list(lengthChange = FALSE))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That gets me pretty close! How do you reference the edited dfs for future use? For example, lets say the user changes cells in df1 and df2, and I use those changes for a calculation. Is there way to reference the modified dfs (and not the original ones)?

Comment: Yes - you can reference the reactiveValues. For example: rv$tables[[“df1”]] to get edited df1 table